# How to disable the Navigation Bar in android

Tags: android

**`As Shown in the pic below`**,

1. *is it possible to disable the navigation bar in android*
2. I am trying to disable all the three functionalities,
3. *Requirement i am working on is a lock screen, so is it possible in android*
4. Any existing answers to support this

---

[image]

Comment: Seems you want to disable hardware functionality.

Comment: Functionality, i am trying to achieve is a lockApp feature

Comment: You can disable navigation and home button menu in `onKeyDown()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the navigation bar by doing the following:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

To make content appear behind the navigation bar you need to use `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION`. You may also need to use `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` to help your app maintain a stable layout.

You may instead want to use immersive Full-Screen Mode. Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the Action Bar by using following style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

For Hiding the navigation bar use the following and refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html).

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```